# Easy way to access the boost::tuple with phoenix

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I would like to access the boost::tuple element with phoenix(c++98)

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::phoenix::placeholders;

    std::vector<boost::tuple<int> > vec;
    vec.push_back(boost::make_tuple(3));
    vec.push_back(boost::make_tuple(4));

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::cout<<boost::get<0>(arg1)<<std::endl);
}
```

But it cannot work, I have tried with std::pair and self define struct, but they cannot work either. Is it possible to access those element with some intuitive, easy solution?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, but still cannot figure out how to access the self define struct element after studying the example you post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find out you can use boost::phoenix::at_c to access tuple element

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::cout<<boost::phoenix::at_c<0>(arg1)<<std::endl);
```

You can access std::pair with phoenix too, but need to include the header

`#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>`

Still lack the example of access self define struct, if I can figure it out I would post it

Edit : you need to include

```
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>
```

else at_c may not found

Comment: To access user-defined structure fields you will have to adapt it to a Boost.Fusion sequence first (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html)). Then you'll be able to access its fields just like you'd do with a tuple.